# Joining 2 datasets where key variable appears in multiple rows in both left and right datasets: R

Tags: r, join

I have two dataframes. The first one has information on individual id, period and city of the workplace. The second dataset contains information on individual id and city of study degrees achieved throughout their lives. One individual can work at different places at the same period as well as may have multiple degree. I wish to add a column to the first dataframe informing whether the individual has a degree from the same city as she is working at the given period.

Consider the very simple example below. Dataframe `mydf1` informs that (i) individual A works in cities x and y at both periods 1 and 2, (ii) invididual B works in city w in periods 1 and 2 and in city k in period 1, (iii) individual C works in city k in period 1. Dataframe `mydf2` shows that (i) individual A has studied in cities x and w, (ii) individual B has studied in cities x and k, and (iii) individual C has studied in cities y and k.

```
mydf1 <- data.frame(id=c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C'),
                   period=c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,1),
                   work_city=c('x','y','x','y','w','k','w','k'))

mydf2 <- data.frame(id=c('A','A','B','B','C','C'),
                    study_city=c('x','w','x','k','y','k'))
```

My output should be as below, where the indicator variable `same_city` is equal to 1 if the value of `work_city` for the respective row coincides with any of the values of variable `study_city` in dataset `mydf2` for that particular individual. For instance: for individual A, variable `same_city` should be 1 if `work_city` is equal to 'x' or 'w', or 0 otherwise.

```
mydf_final <- data.frame(id=c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C'),
                         period=c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,1),
                         work_city=c('x','y','x','y','w','k','w','k'),
                         same_city=c('1','0','1','0','0','1','0','1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution by aggregating `mydf2 by id and putting all study cities in a list. After joining` mydf1`and`mydf2_aggregated`we check if the`work_city`for each row appears in the`study_cities` list:

```
mydf1 <- data.frame(id=c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C'),
                    period=c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,1),
                    work_city=c('x','y','x','y','w','k','w','k'))

mydf2 <- data.frame(id=c('A','A','B','B','C','C'),
                    study_city=c('x','w','x','k','y','k'))
```

Aggregate `mydf2` by `id` and put all values for `study_cities` in a list. Now there is only one row per unique `id`.

```
library(dplyr)
mydf2_aggr <- mydf2 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(study_cities = list(study_city))
```

Join `mydf2` and `mydf2_aggr` on `id` and use the `rowwise` function so that we can use a simple ifelse on each rows `study_cities` list. There might exist solutions without having to use `rowwise`... The columne `study_cities_as_string` I've only added to illustrate my answer!

```
mydf_final <- mydf1 %>% 
  left_join(mydf2_aggr, by="id") %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(study_cities_as_string = paste(study_cities, collapse=","),
         same_city = ifelse(work_city %in% study_cities, 1, 0)) %>% 
  select(-study_cities)
```

`mydf_final` is now:

> ```
>   id    period work_city study_cities_as_string same_city
>   <chr>  <dbl> <chr>     <chr>                      <dbl>
> 1 A          1 x         x,w                            1
> 2 A          1 y         x,w                            0
> 3 A          2 x         x,w                            1
> 4 A          2 y         x,w                            0
> 5 B          1 w         x,k                            0
> 6 B          1 k         x,k                            1
> 7 B          2 w         x,k                            0
> 8 C          1 k         y,k                            1
> ```

Comment: Thanks @dario! Sorry for the delay in replying. I am confused on how R deals with factor variables that should have same levels but appear in different columns / dataframes. For instance, `work_city` and `study_city` should have same levels as they refer to the universe of all cities. How do we know R is considering same levels for these variables as we don't inform it should?  Also, why do we need `rowwise()` above? I would think the `%in%` operator insite `mutate()` would work without it, but I am wrong. When I delete `rowwise()` I get `same_city` only showing 0's.